# Pull data into full calendar using php

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to pull event data into my full calendar using php. I have successfully retrieved the data from the database and converted it to json but I have one problem.

Here is the json outputted:

```
[
   {"id":"53","start":"2013-06-06","title":"Assignment2"},
   {"id":"52","start":"2013-06-07","title":"Assignment1"},
   {"id":"54","start":"2013-06-08","title":"Assignment3"}
]
```

So when I want to put it into my fullcalendar i do this:

```
var class_id = $("#calendar").attr('c_id');
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    dayClick:function(data){
    },
    events: '/classes/get_due_dates/'+c_id
});
```

When I did this nothing was showing up on the calendar but when I copied and pasted the output and removed the quotes surrounding id, start and title it worked fine

Like so:

```
[
   {id:"53",start:"2013-06-06",title:"Assignment2"},
   {id:"52",start:"2013-06-07",title:"Assignment1"},
   {id:"54",start:"2013-06-08",title:"Assignment3"}
]
```

Notice the quotes removed, So my question is how do i convert the output that I am getting and remove those quotes so I can display these events on my calendar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it is what you are looking for.

```
<?php
    $str = '[
   {"id":"53","start":"2013-06-06","title":"Assignment2"},
   {"id":"52","start":"2013-06-07","title":"Assignment1"},
   {"id":"54","start":"2013-06-08","title":"Assignment3"}
]';

    $str = str_replace('{"', '{', $str);
    $str = str_replace('":', ':', $str);
    $str = str_replace(',"', ',', $str);

    echo "<pre>" . $str . "</pre>";
?>
```